# set pdfbookmark for enumerate with \usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}

Tags: pdftex, latex3, pdfscreen

My tex file uses `\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}` and I also want set pdfbookmark for enumerate in this file. I tried

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksdepth=2}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\itemm}[1][]{\item\label{item:#1}\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{anchor:#1}}

\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen} %comment this???

\begin{document}

%===================================================
\section{A}

\begin{enumerate}[{1}.1]

\itemm[1.1] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[11]

\itemm[1.2] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[12]

\end{enumerate}

%===================================================
\section{B}

\begin{enumerate}[{2}.1]

\itemm[2.1] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[21]

\itemm[2.2] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[22]

\itemm[2.3] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I note that the  pdfbookmarks such as `1.1, 1.2,...` only work when we comment `\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}` . Can we remedy this with `\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}` present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfscreen changes the pdfpagemode to none, you can switch back:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksdepth=2}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\itemm}[1][]{\item\label{item:#1}\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{anchor:#1}}

\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen} %comment this???
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseOutlines} %show outlines
\begin{document}

%===================================================
\section{A}

\begin{enumerate}[{1}.1]

\itemm[1.1] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[11]

\itemm[1.2] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[12]

\end{enumerate}

%===================================================
\section{B}

\begin{enumerate}[{2}.1]

\itemm[2.1] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[21]

\itemm[2.2] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[22]

\itemm[2.3] %--------------------------------------------
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tks for replying! However, it still doesn't work. I said it works which means when we click the related  pdfbookmark (e.g. `1.1, 2.1`) it will jump to the target  location. @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: Not just showing outlines but also jumping the to the target location when clicking @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: the package sets the view to Fit, try with `pdfstartview=,pdfview=xyz`

Comment: Wow, `\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}` combined with  `\hypersetup{pdfview=xyz}` works quite well. Amazing! @Ulrike Fischer